# inlineCount not working for non-EF server

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am running following query

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery 
        .from('employees').inlineCount(true).then(function(data) {
          console.log(data.inlineCount); //undefined
});
```

This is the data returned by server (written in python, a non-EF server).

```
{ "inlineCount" : 100, "results" : <result_object> }
```

I am also using jsonResultsAdapter.

```
extractResults: function (data) {
        var results = data.results;
        if (!results) throw new Error("Unable to resolve 'results' property");
        return results;
},
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Will it not work with non-EF source?

Comment: `console.log(data.results.inlineCount)` instead of `console.log(data.inlineCount)`

Comment: Depending on the adapter you are using may not be correct @AdelSal you need to `console.log(data.httpResults.data.inlineCount);` instead of `data.results.inlineCount`

Comment: Nope, not working. Is it because I am using a custom jsonResultsAdapter?

Comment: Very likely, but it should be relatively easy to make it compliant.